# error in my java script when i want to print out the grade

Tags: javascript

i did not encounter any problem when i only print out the student name and their mark , but when i write the code for calculate or return their grade it did not show the grade that i want to .and when i want to enter the student name and marks for  student 1 , it just skip student 2 and ask for student 3 name and grade ... anyone know how to fix it ??  below is my code :

```js
function Average() {
  var text = "";
  var person = new Array();
  var marks = new Array();
  var grade = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    person[i] = window.prompt("enter student name " + (i + 1) + "of 3", "");
    marks[i] = window.prompt("enter student marks " + (i + 1) + "of 3", "");

    for (var i = 0; i < marks.length; i++) {
      if (marks[i] >= 85 && marks[i] < 100) {
        grade[i] = "HD";
      } else if (marks[i] >= 75 && marks[i] < 85) {
        grade[i] = "D";
      } else if (marks[i] >= 65 && marks[i] < 75) {
        grade[i] = "C";
      } else if (marks[i] >= 50 && marks[i] < 35) {
        grade[i] = "P";
      } else if (marks[i] >= 00 && marks[i] < 50) {
        grade[i] = "F";
      }

      text += "the student name  is : " + person[i] + "&nbsp" + "&nbsp" + "theirs marks are : " + marks[i] + grade[i] + "<br>";
    }
    // text += "the student name  is : " + person[i] +"&nbsp"  +"&nbsp" + "theirs marks are : "  + marks[i] +  grade[i] +"<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<p> click this to active the window prompt </p>
<button onclick="Average()"> Click Me </button>
<p id="id"></p>
```

my result :

[image]

Comment: You’re using the iteration variable `i` for _both_ loops. Choose a different variable name.

Comment: guys please help me solve it :(

Comment: @Xufox already gave you the answer.

Comment: @Xufox is it matter if i use same var i as for loop ??

Comment: Think about it. You’re resetting `i` to `0` in your inner loop, even though you want to increment it in your outer loop.

Comment: JavaScript has **function scope** of variables.

Comment: @Xufox  ok so now i have change the second for loop to x and i have change the grade[i] to grade [x]  and at the "text " i also change the grade[i] to grade[x]  , but now it print out 6 times which is look like this :  
 the student name is : abc  theirs marks are : 90HD
the student name is : ee  theirs marks are : 20F
the student name is : ee  theirs marks are : 20F
the student name is : fff  theirs marks are : 80D
the student name is : fff  theirs marks are : 80D
the student name is : fff  theirs marks are : 80D

Comment: @NicholasTower Oh, my bad, thanks. Quickly grazed over the issue and that seemed like the logical candidate.

Comment: @ChaiLiGen Okay, your comment is barely readable. Could you please [edit] your question and clearly state what your _expected_ and what your _actual_ result is? Also, explain to me: why do you need the inner loop?

Comment: @Xufox  nevermind i solve it .. btw thx for helping :)

Comment: @ChaiLiGen Good for you. I’m still going to recommend the [Rubber Duck Debug](https://rubberduckdebugging.com) method and [using](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
function Average() {
  var text = "";
  var person = new Array();
  var marks = new Array();
  var grade = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    person[i] = window.prompt("enter student name " + (i + 1) + "of 3", "");
    marks[i] = window.prompt("enter student marks " + (i + 1) + "of 3", "");

  }
  for (var i = 0; i < marks.length; i++) {
    if (marks[i] >= 85 && marks[i] <= 100) {
      grade[i] = "HD";
    } else if (marks[i] >= 75 && marks[i] < 85) {
      grade[i] = "D";
    } else if (marks[i] >= 65 && marks[i] < 75) {
      grade[i] = "C";
    } else if (marks[i] >= 50 && marks[i] < 65) {
      grade[i] = "P";
    } else if (marks[i] >= 00 && marks[i] < 50) {
      grade[i] = "F";
    }

    text += "The student name is: " + person[i] + "&nbsp" + "&nbsp" + "their marks are: " + marks[i] + grade[i] + "<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<p> click this to active the window prompt </p>
<button onclick="Average()"> Click Me </button>
<p id="id"></p>
```

You need to move the inner loop out of the first loop.

Comment: Thanks, @met4000 for pointing out the 65, not 35 and < 100 errors.

Answer (score 2):

You have not ended your prompt for loop before starting the calculation for loop. It should read:

```js
function Average() {
  var text = "";
  var person = new Array();
  var marks = new Array();
  var grade = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    person[i] = window.prompt("enter student name " + (i + 1) + "of 3", "");
    marks[i] = window.prompt("enter student marks " + (i + 1) + "of 3", "");
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < marks.length; i++) {
    if (marks[i] >= 85 && marks[i] < 100) {
      grade[i] = "HD";
    } else if (marks[i] >= 75 && marks[i] < 85) {
      grade[i] = "D";
    } else if (marks[i] >= 65 && marks[i] < 75) {
      grade[i] = "C";
    } else if (marks[i] >= 50 && marks[i] < 35) {
      grade[i] = "P";
    } else if (marks[i] >= 00 && marks[i] < 50) {
      grade[i] = "F";
    }

    text += "the student name  is : " + person[i] + "&nbsp" + "&nbsp" + "theirs marks are : " + marks[i] + grade[i] + "<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<p> click this to active the window prompt </p>
<button onclick="Average()"> Click Me </button>
<p id="id"></p>
```

Additionally, your marking system does not account for 100 (it's only <100), and I think you typed '35' instead of '65':

```
if (marks[i] >= 85 && marks[i] <= 100) {
...
} else if (marks[i] >= 50 && marks[i] < 65) {
```

Hope this helps!